# Application Insight in MVC and testing from another C# Test project

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a MVC application the application insight is working fine from that application. ,We have a test C# class project, from there i am invoking a method which is having the code to trigger the application insight event, but it is throwing following error.,

`Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector' could not be loaded`

I copied the MVC applicationInsight.cofig file into the C# test web project and added entries in the

```
<httpmodules>
    <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
</httpmodules>
```

Application 1 -> Testproject C# Class project

```
{

    Appinsight a = new Appinsight();
    a.Function1();
}
```

MVC WebApplication

```
Class Appinsight
{
  Funciton1()
  {
     TelemetryClient o = new TelemetryClient();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, another issue on the test project., the test project is working and it is hitting the application insight through the classes which is there in the MVC application without any error... But the details i am not able to see it in the Azure .... Any idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it can't load assemblies, that means that when your test project runs, some of the app insights classes couldn't be found.  you need to make sure that wherever your test code is running from, that all of the same assemblies that are deployed to the website are also deployed to wherever the test code is running from.

Comment: Just to tack on here. We've seen this come up when the web.config is missing a bindingRedirect to the Agent.Intercept. Check your web.config for the following line.

`<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.1.0" newVersion="1.2.1.0"/>`

Comment: wouldn't that only matter if you have multiple versions of that assembly deployed somewhere, and you want to guarantee that you get a specific one?  ideally you shouldn't have multiple versions of that assembly deployed, though.

Comment: Good catch, I put the incorrect version in there. The newVersion value should be `2.0.1.0`. What's been happening is the 2.1.0 DependencyCollector is tied to version 1.2.1.0. And people will deploy the newer version of the Agent.Intercept but not include the binding redirect. Or, vice versa, they will deploy the web.config with the updated redirect, but have the old file.